# Cheaper way to mint NFTs to addresses( airdrop) by using ERC721 contract?

Tags: nft, erc-721

I want to create an NFT contract and mint some NFTs to some addresses. I have a function as follow:

```
function airdrop(uint256 tokenId, address _receiver)
    public
    onlyOwner {
    _safeMint(_receiver, tokenId); }
```

This function is fine but the gas fee is high since I need to call this function for several times. Is there any other way to do airdrop so that I can reduce the gas fee?
I will spend the gas fee so the method of asking receivers to pay is not expected.

Comment: I think I can help, as I do have some experience with optimizing NFT minting. But I would need to see more of your code. For example, I would need to see the NFT structure and how you whitelisted addresses for airdrop, or how you call the function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use lazy mint with signatures but if you have large airdrops you should use the [Merkle tree](https://github.com/protofire/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/MerkleProof.sol). you get the list of the addresses and need to install merkletreejs and keccak256.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/merkletreejs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keccak256

```
const [owner, user1, user2, user3, user4] = await ethers.getSigners();
    let listOfAddresses = [
        user1.address, 
        user2.address,
        user3.address,
        user4.address, 
    ];
const leaf = listOfAddresses.map(addrs=> ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['address'], [addrs]));
const merkleTree = new MerkleTree(leaf, keccak256,{sortPairs: true})
const root = merkleTree.getHexRoot(); 
// deploy the contract and add the root of the tree
const deployExample = await instance.deploy('name', 'symbol', merkleTree.getHexRoot());



 const user4ClaimingNFT = merkleTree.getHexProof(leaf[3]);

 // when a user claim an airdrop ... 
 await instance.connect(user4).airdrop(user4.address, user4ClaimingNFT)
 // check the balance ..
 await instance.balanceOf(buyer4.address).then(res=>{
        console.log("balanceOf ", res);
    });
```

in the contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MerkleExample is ERC721 {

bytes32 immutable public root;
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
mapping (address => bool) private isMinted;

constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, bytes32 _root)
ERC721(name, symbol)
{
    root = _root;
}

function airdrop(address account, bytes32[] calldata proof) external
{
    require(account==msg.sender,"not owner" );
    // you can have some requirement by checking how many mint per address
    // or map address -> true/false something like isMinted:
    require(!isMinted[account],"already minted");
    require(_verify(_leaf(account), proof), "Invalid proof");
    isMinted[account] = true;
    safeMint(account);
}

function safeMint(address to) private  {
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
}

function _leaf(address account)
public pure returns (bytes32)
{
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(account));
}

function _verify(bytes32 leaf, bytes32[] memory proof)
public view returns (bool)
{
    return MerkleProof.verify(proof, root, leaf);
}
}
```